# update my repository on github

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I just went up to **github** the project that was working locally on my computer. everything went well and I could upload all my files .. now I would like to know how I can update my repository if I make some changes to my project locally
try the following commands:

```
git add.
git pull origin master
```

I think I'm forgetting something, or I'm using the commands incorrectly, what would be the correct way?

Comment: you need commit and push

Comment: Look at this how to. https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/

Comment: @Alexan apply a commit and then a push, but it only worked once and then I no longer update my local changes in my repository

Comment: you need to do it every time

Comment: It may be helpful to understand the difference between Git and GitHub AND the relationship between them.  https://www.sitepoint.com/screencast-difference-git-github/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your work flow for ensuring that your changes are added correctly to your remote github repo in "normal" cases should follow these stages ..

```
(1) git status
```

Will always tell you what is uncommitted and what needs to be "added" (staged) for committing to your local repo. In fact git will hint to you what it thinks is the next step in your work flow

```
(2) git add <your_file_path_you_can_use_glob_patternsLike_asteriks>

(3) git commit -m "A Nice Subject line for many file commits <enterFromKeyboardGivesYouAnotherLine>
(a) Continue typing more comments which are detailed if necessary <anotherEnterFromKeyboard>
(b) Some more details and do not forget to put closing quote mark"
```

Works in Windows if use the Windows git-bash.exe It uses mingW64 emulator to simulate linux environment. It's very good at it.

You need to commit whatever changes yout want to keep - locally before you can "push" your changes to your github repo remotely ie only after you have told git where your remote git repo is .....

```
(4) git remote add myGitHubOrBitBucketRepo https://github.com/YourGitAppRepo.git
```

Usually the default name for your remote repo on github is given as "origin". But I have been using specific alias branch names which in your case is "myGitHubOrBitBucketRepo"

```
(5) git push -u myGitHubOrBitBucketRepo HEAD:master
```

This command will push your committed changes (aka snap shots in git speak) to YourGitAppRepo.git on github.com onto the master branch and if master on your remote repo is not ahead of your local branch and it is just a couple of commits behind - github.com will accept this push

The -u is the same as --track which means that your local branch positioned @ HEAD will be tracking the master branch at your remote alias myGitHubOrBitBucketRep

In steps 4 & 5 you will have to use a userId and passWord to interact with your remote repo on GitHub.com

```
(6) git status
```

From now on git status will actually tell you whether you are behind or ahead of your remote github repo because of the --track (ing) option you had done in your push

Another useful command to use from this point onwards will be

```
git branch -vv --all
```

An example

```
$ git branch -vv --all
* CurrAsOf18Jan2018             50d1fc6 [remotes/bitbucketFrmWin/master: behind 5] Pedantic but done - gitNotes.txt
  remotes/bitbucketFrmWin/master        58470cd [CurrAsOf18Jan2018] This is really crazy - Spent more than a week - Singleton still gives
```

Over here bitbucketFrmWin is my alias for my remote bitbucket repo
AsOf16Jan2018 is a branch that I am no longer interested
master is my current main branch which I push my changes to from my local repo.

The --all option will also display your local & your "remotes"

Of note is the following 
* CurrAsOf18Jan2018             50d1fc6 [remotes/bitbucketFrmWin/master: behind 5]

The asterik * that is the HEAD of my local branch or at which commit on that branch I am on. Usually it is always at the tip or the HEAD i.e. why it is called the "head"

CurrAsOf18Jan2018 is my local main branch and importantly it is saying that my local is already ahead of my remote branch by 5 commits - it is out of date so I need to update my remote with a "git push"

For now that is just one side of this story. If your remote repo goes ahead then another work-flow would be

```
git fetch --all && git merge --ff-only <theCommitYouWantYouToCatchUpWith>
```

That is altogether another post.

And here is a succinct image which I found courtesy Oliver Steele that displays another version of the basic git workflow life-cycle of versioning
[image: Another Git WorkFlow cycle courtesy Oliver Steele @ osteele.com]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think these steps are to upload my project to github, I already have it uploaded, I need to know how to update if I make any changes to my code or create a new file, and this will also be updated in my repository.

Comment: FeRcHo - effectively what you have above is a whole use case for committing your changes to your local repo, uploading it to your remote and then fetching and updating changes that other's have committed as long as your local commits are just behind your colleague's changes - what I would suggest is to play with a few simple files just to figure out the life cycle of a basic use case so that you can work out what is happening - it's like having a mate who can be quite a "git" to understand but once you do - believe me you quickly forget how difficult he used to be.

Comment: I started with this guide - and believe me it got me on the road https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

Answer (score 27):

```
git add .
git commit -m "my changes" 
git remote add origin https://github.com/zinmyoswe/React-and-Django-Ecommerce.git
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me and I think adding the remote origin is not needed because it is already done while pushing the files in the repository for the first time.
To update the git hub repository with reference to the local repository:

```
git add .
git pull
git push -u origin main
```

Answer (score -1):

git add .
git commit -m "message"
git push

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).